# Index out of bounds bug in my JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, closures, settimeout

There is an error in the following code:

```
generate: function() {
    var generated = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < objectDefinitions.length; j++) {
        var randomNumber;

        if (!objectDefinitions[j].restrictGeneration) {
            continue;
        }

        randomNumber = Math.random();

        if (randomNumber < objectDefinitions[j].probability) {
            generated.push(objectDefinitions[j].createObject());
            objectDefinitions[j].restrictGeneration = true;
            if (j > 5) {
            }
            setTimeout(function() {                 
                //console.log(j);
                objectDefinitions[j].restrictGeneration = false;
            }, objectDefinitions[j].cooldown);
        }
    }
    return generated;
}
```

When the setTimeout "fires" the variable j is 6, which causes an array index out of bounds exception because there are only 6 items in the array. I don't really understand what's going on, I have checked j outside setTimeout and it is never 6, but it seems to change after it's declaration. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I wonder if there is a better title for this question since this seems like a great learning opportunity for novice js programmers and this question should be found!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables `j` it reads is the one you used in the loop so it didn't get "copied".

```
setTimeout(
    (function(k){
        return function() {            
            objectDefinitions[k].restrictGeneration = false;
        };
    }(j))
, objectDefinitions[j].cooldown);
```

This way you `j` is copied in a `k` variable. But there is one `k` variable per iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much, I need to chew over that, but the code worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Your empty if statement executes (by doing nothing), then it moves onto set timeout, with j still greater than 5.

Basically, you should exit at that point, instead of moving on to executing more code after the if statement, OR make an else statement there, so that no further code executes if j > 5.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately j is never > 5 at that point. That's the weird thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to *closures*.

You're seeing a value of `6` because `j++` is run one last time triggering the exit of the for loop.  Thus, that *closure* now has a `j` of 6.  When `setTimeout` executes (which is after the `for` loop completes, it's executing in the context of that closure.

You'll need to move this code into its own closure, which is done by moving it into its own function.  Something like:

```
generate: function() {
    var generated = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < objectDefinitions.length; j++)
    {
       handleIteration(generated, j); // Re-factor your code into a new function
    }

    return generated;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did think it could be something to do with scope/closures, but for some reason I got quite confused as to what was going on, I (incorrectly) thought j would be copied rather than referenced. I solved this by using an anonymous function as described by xavierm02, using a separate function is potentially more elegant though so thank you.